# Eclipse activity_main.xml and my test phone is showing different theme Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, material-design, android-theme

I met a problem here.

I just started an empty `Android` project and changed the theme to `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light`. The theme does not change in `Eclipse` rendering preview but does change and shows correctly on my `Galaxy S6` test phone.

Anyone give a solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Android Studio** in the design of `XML` file you will see theme selection as shown in below image.

[image]

For **Eclipse**:
[image]

Click on and select desirable theme for your `Activity`.